# Wrap DIV to content only wraps when content is on one line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to wrap multiple `fieldsets` within a surrounding `div`. The div wraps OK when the browser is large enough to fit all the `fieldsets` on one line, but when they flow to the next line, the div border snaps to the right edge of the browser window (Chrome). How can I overcome this without using setting widths or using JS?

HTML

```
 <div id="wrapper" class="display-inline-block">
        <fieldset id="f1" class="display-inline-block">
            <legend>F1</legend>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="f2" class="display-inline-block">
            <legend>F2</legend>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div
```

CSS

```
 #wrapper
    {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .display-inline-block
    { 
        display:-moz-inline-stack;
        display:inline-block;
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at this for the past 5 mins and doesn't look like it's possible with pure CSS other than possibly a media query.

Comment: This is not an answer, please make this as a comment. If you don't have permissions just be patient

Comment: Don't have permissions. I realise it wasn't an answer but seeing as I spent a while trying to  help you I thought you might appreciate some feedback... so sorry for not being patient.